# I need to read a xml file and change the id of each tag to id+tagname

Tags: java, xml

I need to read a file and find and replace some text in the same file without closing reader.

Suggest any easy ways...

Iam reading the file as follows. How can I write it to the same file.

```
private static void readFile(String path) throws IOException {
        makeFolderStructure(path);
        for (String xmlNameString : xmlFileNamesList) {
            FileReader xmlFile = new FileReader(
                    path + "\\xml\\" + xmlNameString + ".xml");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(xmlFile);
            try {
                String line = br.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    if (line.contains("<") && line.indexOf(" ") != -1) {
                        String tagName = line.substring(line.indexOf("<") + 1,
                                line.indexOf(" "));
                        if (line.indexOf("id") != -1) {
                            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
                            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
                            while (m.find()) {
                                String tagId = (m.group(1));
                                System.out.println(tagId+"_"+tagName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            } finally {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use xslt to apply changes to xml and then save it to the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like reading: Check this out https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm

If you don't:

There are a number of XML parsers out there

- [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)
- [Woodstox](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/WoodstoxHome)
- [XOM](http://xom.nu/)
- [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)
- [Xerces-J](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/)
- [Crimson](http://xml.apache.org/crimson/)

I highly recommend you to check them out. Most of them are very easy to use check out the documentation of each one of them and decide which one you would like to use. What you're trying to do with the above code is reinventing the wheel, take a look at the above-mentioned API's and focus on writing new code.

Comment: please explain what it is that you want, the above API's allow you to change everything in an XML-file. If you believe it answered your question mark the answer as answered else please try to explain what it is you're trying to achieve so i can help.